# Getting difference between two dates in days

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, linq, date, difference

I have a specific problem where I have records in my DB table like the following:

```
LastUpdated

10 January 2017
```

(The dates are stored in the database as a DateTime type.)

Now I need to fetch the difference in days between today's date and the last one *including* today's date. So, for example, today is the 12th, so the amount of days would be 2.

Now the second part of the problem is that I have another table setup like the following:

```
TransactionDate

1 January 2017
2 January 2017
3 January 2017
4 January 2017
5 January 2017
6 January 2017
7 January 2017
8 January 2017
9 January 2017
10 January 2017
```

So now after I perform a LINQ the updated results in my DBTable would look like the following:

```
3 January 2017
4 January 2017
5 January 2017
6 January 2017
7 January 2017
8 January 2017
9 January 2017
10 January 2017
11 January 2017
12 January 2017
```

So basically I'm trying to get the difference between the current date and the last updated date and then add it to the transaction details table. Upon adding the difference between two dates, I want to remove as much as the days in difference has been added, so that the total date span remains 10 days...

Can someone help me out with this?

Edit: this is the code so far:

```
 var usr = ctx.SearchedUsers.FirstOrDefault(x => x.EbayUsername == username);
 var TotalDays = (DateTime.Now - usr.LastUpdatedAt).Value.TotalDays;
```

Is this a correct way of fetching the difference between two dates like I've mentioned above?

Now after this I perform an HTTP request where I get the remaining two dates and insert it like:

```
ctx.TransactionDetails.Add(RemainingTwoDates);
ctx.SaveChanges();
```

Now I have dates expanding from 1st January to 12th of January, but I want to remove 1st and 2nd of January so that the total range of days stays 10;

How can I do this ?

Comment: @AndrewMorton yes it's datetime format :) I've just shown the dates in this format here so that people can read it easier

Comment: When you say LINQ, what dialect (ORM) do you have in mind?

Comment: @AndrewMorton Yes one moment I'll show it

Comment: @IvanStoev LINQ like using lambda expressions ...

Comment: I meant LINQ to Objects, LINQ to SQL, LINQ to Entities (EF or EF Core) etc.

Comment: @IvanStoev LINQ to Entities - EF 6.0

Comment: @AndrewMorton I've updated my question

Comment: @User987 Why not just remove transactions with dates less than 10 days ago. and then add dates from the last update to now.

Comment: @Nkosi Can you show me an example how to do that ?? I'm not sure confident working with dates, I 've always made mistakes with them. Could you help me out please? :)

Comment: @User987 you tables example were rather vague but check my suggestion below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove transaction dates that are older than 10 days ago.

```
ctx.TransactionDetails.Add(RemainingTwoDays);

//Now you want to remove those older than 10 days
var today = DateTime.Today;
var tenDaysAgo = today.AddDays(-10);
var oldTrandactions = ctx.TransactionDetails.Where(t => t.TransactionDate <= tenDaysAgo).ToList();

foreach (var t in oldTrandactions) {
    ctx.TransactionDetails.Remove(t);
}

ctx.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: Hey @Nkosi this works quite nicely thanks! But how can I include the todays date into the counter number ? For example if i have transactions with dates: 12/11/10/9/8/7/6/5/4/3/2/1th of January and I wanna remove all those older than 2 days, this current method that you posted leaves following dates: 12/11/10 <<< this is what leaves in the DB... How can I include the todays date as well in count for removal. So if I wanna remove older than 2 days, I'd be left with 12/11 January

Comment: Note the slight update I made with the `<=` less than or equal to.